# Destructure a Flow object type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, flowtype, react-apollo

I'm generating Flow types for Apollo Client, and I currently have this:

```
type FetchModuleQuery = {|
  // Fetch single module
  module: ?{|
    // ID
    id: string,
    // Name
    name: string,
    // Fetch list of assignments for module
    assignments: ?Array<?{|
      // Created date
      createdAt: any,
      // ID
      id: string,
      // Name
      name: string
    |}>
  |}
|};
```

However, this data is located in my parent component `<Component1 />`, and I render its child component like so:

```
<Component2 assignments={this.props.module.assignments} />
```

This works fine; I'm doing all the checks I need to do to keep Flow happy. However, I can't figure out the cleanest way of typing my `<Component2 />`; ideally, I want to use this existing `FetchModuleQuery` object type, and not create anything new.

Any ideas?

Comment: In typescript you can do `FetchModuleQuery["module"]["assignments"]`, don't know the flow equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the cleanest way is to extract a "helper" type and use that, like in *Ross Allen*'s answer.

Alternatively, you can use the [$PropertyType](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-propertytype) utility type.

```
type Component2Props = {
  assignments: $PropertyType<$PropertyType<FetchModuleQuery, 'module'>, 'assignments'>
}
```

This is basically the same as TypeScript's `FetchModuleQuery["module"]["assignments"]`, which *Jonas W.* suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can [import and export Flow types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/#importing-and-exporting-types-) with a syntax similar to importing and exporting real modules. For your case, you could extract `assignments` as another type and do something like the following:

**Component1.js**:

```
export type FetchModuleQueryAssignments = ?Array<?{|
  // Created date
  createdAt: any,
  // ID
  id: string,
  // Name
  name: string
|}>;

export type FetchModuleQuery = {|
  ...,
  assignments: FetchModuleQueryAssignments,
|};
```

**Component2.js**:

```
import type { FetchModuleQueryAssignments } from './Component1';
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that; however, I want specifically to get the `assignments` section of the `FetchModuleQuery` object type, perhaps as a separate object type. Is that possible?

Comment: @think123 Oh okay I misunderstood. Yes, you can extract that into another type and export that type. I updated my answer.